# css3 transition: firefox makes on hover out and chrome in hover in

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, transition

I would like both to behave like webkit, but for some reason in webkit works as I expected but -moz- does the animation when mouseout the .porftolio item,

Any idea why?

CSS:

```
.portfolio-item {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0.5%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s all ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s all ease;
  transition: 0.4s all ease;
}
.portfolio-item a:hover:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), transparent 100%);
}
.portfolio-item h4, .portfolio-item img {
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s all ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s all ease;
  transition: 0.4s all ease;
}
.portfolio-item img {
  width: 100%;
  hegight: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.portfolio-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.portfolio-item h4 {
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*@include transform(scale(.5));*/
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  /* sino en safari no va */
  width: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-2px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2px);
  transform: translateX(-2px);
}
.portfolio-item:hover {
  z-index: 9;
}
.portfolio-item:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.07);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.07);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.07);
  transform: scale(1.07);
}
.portfolio-item:hover h4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(3px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(3px);
  transform: translateX(3px);
  /*-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  -moz-animation-name: shake;
  -o-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;*/
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul><li class="portfolio-item"  style="background-color: #6220E5;">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/dddddd/cccccc" alt="camper" />
                                    <h4>Text goes here</h4>
                                </a>
</li></ul>
```

Test:
http://jsfiddle.net/kuX39/

-EDIT-

Funny thing is that I noticed that if instead of applying it to :hover i apply it to .hover and toggle the class then the animations works the same... :S

Comment: Thanks for the note ;)  (i am actually using compass and this is the generated .css)

Comment: it's worth pointing out that the whole point of the prefixing system is to denote features that are still considered experimental and/or haven't been finalised in terms of spec or features. The implication is that if it's got a prefix, you can't necessarily rely on it working the same cross-browser. That's kinda the point.

Comment: The thing is that I'm using compass.. instead of all this prefixes i just type @include border-radius(5px) ant the generated .css contains all the prefixes... but do you think this is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this rule:

```
.portfolio-item a:hover:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), transparent 100%);
}
```

where you define all the after pseudoelement only in the hover state. If the a element is not hovered, the pseudo element is undefined, and can take whatever value the browser decides.

If you set  the same on the un-hovered element, it works fine.

```
.portfolio-item a:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), transparent 100%);
}
```

### [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/kuX39/1/)

By the way, my firefox version is using transition and not moz-transition